# With a data-only use of WebRTC and "RTCMultiConnection" lib, did I still need the iceServers?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm working on a WebRTC application, using the RTCMultiConnection library with only data (no audio nor video). My project only need to send messages between multiple users (into a same session).

And when I inspecting my project, I see the library can call some iceServer, as a stun server from Google.

I found the purpose of these stun/turn servers (bypass NAT, firewall, ...), but I don't find clearly if they are still needed with Data-only use of the WebRTC (because people seems using it for voip/video stream), and what datas they take from users?
(only IP? Only one-time? Are they working as relay and so could dump messages between my users?)

Comment: you need that server to introduce a pair of peers. without another server, i think you can also only connect a single pair of devices, but it would be cool if i was wrong.

Comment: I thought that was only the role of the signaling server ... It means that differente people really need to use the same STUN server to be put in relation? 

To be more precise about my project, it is a Chrome extension, and I was thinking about maybe remove STUN servers into the libs file or allow users to parameterize a list of STUN server they accept to use...

Comment: How is the data going to get through NATs without ICE? The video stream is a type of data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is still sent peer-to-peer(not transferred through a server...unless a TURN server is needed). So, you still transfer the SDPs between the peers with your signalling server, but with a data connection entry instead of audio or video. Ice candidates will still need to be gathered and shared so that the peers can connect and then send data directly between each other.

The data does ***NOT*** go through the signalling server. It is still peer-to-peer if you are using a webrtc data channel peerconnection.

Now, if you are only sending text messages, you could use another solution(that is NOT webrtc) that sends the message in a JSON object to a server that then relays the traffic to the other users in the chat. Again, this is NOT a webrtc solution and in no way will use webrtc.